# typescirpt how can i define ...props interface?

Tags: typescript

I am using
`react-pagination` (node package)

so i installed `@types/react-pagination`

and i created custom componet for `ReactPaginate`

`ReactPaginate` have so many props.
so i created `...props`
that object contain `ReactPaginate's` props.

`@types/react-pagination` have interface ReactPaginateProps

so i tried

```js
interface IProps {
  onPageChange?():any;
  props: ReactPaginateProps; // ❓❓❓
}


const MYPagination: React.SFC<IProps> = ({
  onPageChange, ...props
}) => {
<ReactPaginate {...props}/>
}
```

I hoped
If `...prop` include one of (`ReactPaginateProps`),
then type ok!

please teach me how to create `...pros's` interface?

and react-pagination props interface is

```
export interface ReactPaginateProps {
    /**
     * The total number of pages.
     */
    pageCount: number;

    /**
     * The range of pages displayed.
     */
    pageRangeDisplayed: number;

    /**
     * The number of pages to display for margins.
     */
    marginPagesDisplayed: number;

    /**
     * Label for the `previous` button.
     */
    previousLabel?: React.ReactNode;

    /**
     * Label for the `next` button.
     */
    nextLabel?: React.ReactNode;

    /**
     * Label for ellipsis.
     */
    breakLabel?: string | React.ReactNode;

    /**
     * The classname on tag `li` of the ellipsis element.
     */
    breakClassName?: string;

    /**
     * The classname on tag `a` of the ellipsis element.
     */
    breakLinkClassName?: string;

    /**
     * The method to call when a page is clicked. Exposes the current page object as an argument.
     */
    onPageChange?(selectedItem: { selected: number }): void;

    /**
     * The initial page selected.
     */
    initialPage?: number;

    /**
     * To override selected page with parent prop.
     */
    forcePage?: number;

    /**
     * Disable onPageChange callback with initial page. Default: false
     */
    disableInitialCallback?: boolean;

    /**
     * The classname of the pagination container.
     */
    containerClassName?: string;

    /**
     * The classname on tag `li` of each page element.
     */
    pageClassName?: string;

    /**
     * The classname on tag `a` of each page element.
     */
    pageLinkClassName?: string;

    /**
     * The classname for the active page.
     */
    activeClassName?: string;

    /**
     * The classname for the active link.
     */
    activeLinkClassName?: string;

    /**
     * The classname on tag `li` of the `previous` button.
     */
    previousClassName?: string;

    /**
     * The classname on tag `li` of the `next` button.
     */
    nextClassName?: string;

    /**
     * The classname on tag `a` of the `previous` button.
     */
    previousLinkClassName?: string;

    /**
     * The classname on tag `a` of the `next` button.
     */
    nextLinkClassName?: string;

    /**
     * The classname for disabled `previous` and `next` buttons.
     */
    disabledClassName?: string;

    /**
     * The method is called to generate the href attribute value on tag a of each page element.
     */
    hrefBuilder?(pageIndex: number): void;

    /**
     * Extra context to add to the aria-label HTML attribute.
     */
    extraAriaContext?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface IProps extends ReactPaginateProps {
  onPageChange?: () => any;
}
```